# Find learge $\epsilon$ neighbourhood

Tags: real-analysis

Learning epsilon definitions.

Find the largest $\epsilon$ such that S contains an $\epsilon$ nieghbourhood of $x_{0}$

i) $x_{0}=\frac {3}{4}, S= [ \frac {1}{2},1)$

$\frac {1}{4} -\frac {\epsilon}{2}$

ii) $x_{0}= \frac {2}{3} S=[ \frac {1}{2}, \frac {3}{2}]$

$\epsilon=1$

iii) $x_{0}= 5  $ $S=(-1, \infty) $

$\epsilon =6 $

iv) $x_{0}= 1 $ $S=(0,2)$

$\epsilon =1$

Comment: What are you trying to ask? Do you want people to verify your work? If so, you should explain how you arrived at your results.

Comment: There is no answers in my text i would like to know if correct or how to do these problems correctly they are reccomended to learn by teacher.

Comment: 2 is wrong, and I don't understand how you got $\epsilon = 1$. Otherwise, the rest are correct.

Comment: What is the answer to i) again? It should be of the form $\epsilon=blah$ instead of $\frac14-\frac\epsilon2$.